# Have a function that generate palindromic string with a wild card character in the middle. Need help to improve it

Tags: python

I got this function that is a generator of palindromes of a certain range length that depending on if a string is a odd palindrome or not insert a wild card character in the middle position.

```
def get_strand_complement(sequence):
"""Returns the complement strand of the sequence."""
seq = sequence.upper()
change = str.maketrans('ACGT', 'TGCA')
return seq.translate(change)

def get_all_dna_palindromes(alphabet, kmin, kmax):
"""A generator that yields all palindromic strings in a given length range, 
including odd palindromes.
Input:
    max_length - An integer specifying the maximum length palindromes to 
                 be yielded.
    min_length - An integer specifying the minimum length palindromes to
                 be yielded, if not specified defaults to 2.
Output:
    palindrome - palindromic string length within the specified range.
                 An even length palindrome is defined as some sequence
                 ABCC'B'A' (C'B'A' = reverse complement of ABC).
                 We also allow for odd palindromes which are of the form:
                 ABCXC'B'A' where X is one of the two wildcards specifying 
                 charcters W for A or T, and S for C or G.

This function is a generator that yields all possible palindromics in a given 
length range. It allow for odd length palindromes, that presents a wild card
charcter in the center of the palindrome. 
I.E. we allow the following as valid palindromes:
  sequence:            5' AATATT   ...   AATCATT   ...  AATAATT 3'
  Reverse complement:  3' TTATAA   ...   AATGATT   ...  TTATTAA 5'

  yielded as:             AATATT         AATSATT        AATWATT
"""
#Negative lengths make no sense in this context.
if kmin < 0 or kmax < 0 or isinstance(kmin, float) or isinstance(kmax, float):
    print("ERROR: kmin or kmax cannot have negative values or be floats.",file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
#Each palindrome consists of length/2 bases, followed by its reverse complement
#if even, or followed by one of two possible base pairs, and then the reverse
#complement if odd, hence we generate each possible combination of "ACGT" for
#length/2, and use this to construct palindromes.
for k in range(kmin, kmax + 1):
    for kmer in itertools.product(alphabet,repeat=k//2):
        #Need to use join as product returns a tuple, not a string.
        kmer=''.join(kmer)
        if k % 2 == 0:
            palindrome = kmer + get_reverse_complement(kmer)
            yield palindrome
        else:
            for base in "WS":
                palindrome = kmer + base + get_reverse_complement(kmer)
                yield palindrome
```

The output is like this:

```
list(get_all_dna_palindromes('ACGT', 5, 5))
['AAWTT',


'AASTT',
 'ACWGT',
 'ACSGT',
 'AGWCT',
 'AGSCT',
 'ATWAT',
 'ATSAT',
 'CAWTG',
 'CASTG',
 'CCWGG',
 'CCSGG',
 'CGWCG',
 'CGSCG',
 'CTWAG',
 'CTSAG',
 'GAWTC',
 'GASTC',
 'GCWGC',
 'GCSGC',
 'GGWCC',
 'GGSCC',
 'GTWAC',
 'GTSAC',
 'TAWTA',
 'TASTA',
 'TCWGA',
 'TCSGA',
 'TGWCA',
 'TGSCA',
 'TTWAA',
 'TTSAA']
```

I would like to add a argument that I could choose to add 2 or 3 middle characters. It would allowed to search for bigger palindromic sequences to compute some statistics for under-over represented strings in a text for example.

Any tip? I try to use mid=1 as arg and use:

```
if mid == mid: for b1, b2 in zip('WS', random.choice('WS'):
```

But it give me some output but I am not happy with random.choice, because I don't know if it could change the real counts at the end.

There are any way that I could choose a letter from alphabet ('ACGT') and insert 2 or even three
wild cards in the middle position?
like : AAAAWSTTTT or AAAAWWWTTTT or AAAASWWTTTT or AAAASSWTTTT or AAAASSSTTTT and vice versa?

Thank you by your time and patience!

Paulo

Answer (score 0):

I thank you all for your help.

But I got this answer since I put my question here!

```
def insert_wild_cards(word,num_wild_card=1):
word = word.upper()
mononuc = {'A': 'W', 
           'C': 'S', 
           'G': 'S', 
           'T': 'W'}
wild_cards_dimers = {'AA': 'WW',  'AC': 'WS','AG': 'WS',
                     'AT': 'WW', 'CA': 'SW', 'CC': 'SS',
                     'CG': 'SS', 'CT': 'SW', 'GA': 'SW',
                     'GC': 'SS', 'GG': 'SS', 'GT': 'SW',
                     'TA': 'WW', 'TC': 'WS', 'TG': 'WS',
                     'TT': 'WW'}
wild_cards_trimers = {'AAA': 'WWW', 'AAC': 'WWS', 'AAG': 'WWS',
                      'AAT': 'WWW', 'ACA': 'WSW', 'ACC': 'WSS',
                      'ACG': 'WSS', 'ACT': 'WSW', 'AGA': 'WSW',
                      'AGC': 'WSS', 'AGG': 'WSS', 'AGT': 'WSW',
                      'ATA': 'WWW', 'ATC': 'WWS', 'ATG': 'WWS',
                      'ATT': 'WWW', 'CAA': 'SWW', 'CAC': 'SWS',
                      'CAG': 'SWS', 'CAT': 'SWW', 'CCA': 'SSW',
                      'CCC': 'SSS', 'CCG': 'SSS', 'CCT': 'SSW',
                      'CGA': 'SSW', 'CGC': 'SSS', 'CGG': 'SSS',
                      'CGT': 'SSW', 'CTA': 'SWW', 'CTC': 'SWS',
                      'CTG': 'SWS', 'CTT': 'SWW', 'GAA': 'SWW',
                      'GAC': 'SWS', 'GAG': 'SWS', 'GAT': 'SWW',
                      'GCA': 'SSW', 'GCC': 'SSS', 'GCG': 'SSS',
                      'GCT': 'SSW', 'GGA': 'SSW', 'GGC': 'SSS',
                      'GGG': 'SSS', 'GGT': 'SSW', 'GTA': 'SWW',
                      'GTC': 'SWS', 'GTG': 'SWS', 'GTT': 'SWW',
                      'TAA': 'WWW', 'TAC': 'WWS', 'TAG': 'WWS',
                      'TAT': 'WWW', 'TCA': 'WSW', 'TCC': 'WSS',
                      'TCG': 'WSS', 'TCT': 'WSW', 'TGA': 'WSW',
                      'TGC': 'WSS', 'TGG': 'WSS', 'TGT': 'WSW',
                      'TTA': 'WWW', 'TTC': 'WWS', 'TTG': 'WWS',
                      'TTT': 'WWW'}
mid = len(word)//2
# all odd words can receive 1 wild card char
if num_wild_card == 1 and word[:mid] == get_reverse_complement(word[mid+1:]) and len(word) % 2 != 0:
        return word[:mid] + mononuc[word[mid]] + word[mid+1:]
# the even words can receive two wild card chars
if num_wild_card == 2 and word[:mid-1] == get_reverse_complement(word[mid+1:]) and len(word) % 2 == 0:
        return  word[:mid-1] + wild_cards_dimers[word[mid-1:mid+1]] + word[mid+1:]
        # only odd words can return a word with 3 chars wild cards
if num_wild_card == 3 and word[:mid-1] == get_reverse_complement( word[mid+2:]) and len(word) % 2 != 0 and\
len(word) >= 5:
        return word[:mid-1] + wild_cards_trimers[word[mid-1:mid+2]] + word[mid+2:]
else:
    return word

insert_wild_cards('CCtGG', 1) = 'CCWGG'
for word in words[:10]:
print(insert_wild_cards(word, 3), ':', word)
CSWSG : CCTGG
CSWSG : CCAGG
GWWWC : GAATC
GWWWC : GATTC
GSWSC : GGACC
GSWSC : GGTCC
GSSSC : GCCGC
CWSWG : CTCAG
CWSWG : CAGTG
ASSST : ACCGT
```